# Selinux must need auditing support? Can audit2allow be used instead?

Tags: audit, selinux, auditing, audit-trail, libselinux

I have seen that selinux need to enable auditing support. I want to know the difference between audit and audit2allow, can I just use audit2allow instead of audit?
It seems that no audit support in android code, only audit2allow.

For the audit, I mean the audit package at http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`audit` is a daemon, which log denied access ([AVC](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/chap-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Troubleshooting.html)) into `/var/log/audit/audit.log`

`audit2allow` is a user-tool to transfer AVP-log into a SELinux-Policy.

examples:

- show reason for denied access: `cat audit.log | audit2why`
- create SELinux-Policy foo.pp: `cat audit.log | audit2allow -M foo`